# No sources in EKEventStore

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, calendar, ekeventstore

I have a weird problem where my EKEventStore instance doesn't contain any sources.

What it's strange is that in some of my phones works(Get the EKSourceTypeLocal and create the calendar) and in some doesn't, I've spent a lot of time changing calendar settings but I haven't been able to come with a pattern or something.

Any ideas?

Comment: You are probably going to need to supply some code.  Another question, what iOS versions are you running.  Note that in iOS 6 you must use the -requestAccessToEntityType:completion: method after initialization, and before you try to get any data.

Comment: If you could post some code, we might be able to help, but I think Jared makes a good point. Big difference in iOS 6.

Comment: @JaredKipe That was what I was missing, thanks! can you put it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Will do, glad it worked out for you without much trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When on iOS6, ensure that you call -requestAccessToEntityType:completion: method after initialization, and before you try to get any data.

Comment: Another weird thing is that I have my gmail-calendar account linked the code works (Doesn't throw any error) but I can't see al the created events until I unlink the gmail-calendar account, any thoughts about it?

Answer (score 1):

Check the privacy settings. If the user disallowed access to the calendar (iOS 6) for this given app then you don't get any information back.